# Wordpress list category links

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I have this code

```
<?php wp_list_categories('include=3,5,4&orderby=id&title_li='); ?>
        <li <?php if (is_home()) { echo " class=\"active\"";}?>><a
            href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">All Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div id="topHead">
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $exclude = get_option('ss_blogexclude');
            query_posts('cat=-8,-9,-10' . $exclude .'&paged=' . $paged);
    ?>

        <div class="post">
            <!-- Start the Loop. -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

What's not working when I clicked on a category it doesn't show me the post from that category yet it still displays all....

Comment: Is this code above the start of The Loop?

Comment: yes this is the code above the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the code to :

```
<?php if(is_home()) { 
        query_posts( array(
            'showposts' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
            'cat' => '-8,-9,-10')
        );
    }?>
```